# Using tsvector update trigger in Postgres trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a `tsvector` column that I want to update when the row changes. For an `INSERT` I am using this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER albums_vector_insert BEFORE INSERT
ON albums
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
 tsvector_update_trigger('search_vector', 'pg_catalog.english', 'name')
```

Which works fine, seemingly. I would like to use another trigger on `UPDATE` clauses, but I only want it to fire when the name actually changes, so I dont waste cycles updating the search vector needlessly. I've tried this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER albums_vector_update BEFORE UPDATE ON albums
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
        tsvector_update_trigger(search_vector, 'pg_catalog.english', name);
    END IF;
```

But this throws 2 errors when I try to create the trigger:

```
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NEW"
LINE 3:  IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
            ^
Error : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
LINE 1: END IF
            ^
```

From my understanding, if I use the trigger procedure syntax, ala:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION something() RETURNS TRIGGER`

then associate my function with a trigger, then I wont be able to use the built-in `tsvector_update_trigger` function and will need to handle the `ts_vector` manipulation myself. Hence my trying to use the all-in-one-trigger+procedure syntax...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION albums_vector_update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        new.search_vector = to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', COALESCE(NEW.name, ''));
    END IF;
    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
            new.search_vector = to_tsvector('pg_catalog.english', COALESCE(NEW.name, ''));
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON albums
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE albums_vector_update();
```

Comment: There is a typo in the code. You should have a BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE trigger, because NEW is ignored on AFTER triggers.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative could be something like distinct from, it really helped me a few times. Untested code though.

```
CREATE TRIGGER albums_vector_update 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON albums
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD.name IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.name)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(search_vector, 'pg_catalog.english', NEW.name);
```

Comment: This saved me either. I was in trouble with "<>" operator but "DISTINCT FROM" is a bit different than "<>" expression, when you comparate a `NEW.name` with an `OLD.name` which is null before. I'm not a DBA but in my narrow experiences, i saw that, when `OLD.name` is null and `NEW.name` is "something non null",  "NEW.name <> OLD.name" expression returns false but `NEW.name IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.name` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert row you don't have to check this condition, actually you can't as there is no OLD record so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER albums_vector_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON albums
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(search_vector, 'pg_catalog.english', name);
```

For update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER albums_vector_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON albums
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD.name IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.name)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger(search_vector, 'pg_catalog.english', name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The name comparison logic needs to go into the tsvector_update_trigger procedure code.
something like:

```
IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
       -- Do tsvector update
    END IF;
END IF;
```

Then create a trigger that is called before INSERT and UPDATE